# Why very slow animation in viewport? Blender 2.8

Tags: modeling

I'm doing an EXPLODED VIEW/ANIM of a MID TOWER DESKTOP with all the components modeled.

In Blender 2.8, I was wondering why my project when in animation it is so slow. In fact, dragging and moving objects is lagging. My model is a DESKTOP build with all the pc parts in it ranging from mother board, gpu, cpu, fans, power etc. the full setup. Thing is, I cannot give a total number of POLYCOUNT because I do not know where to find it :wink:

The CPU utilization is not high, the GPU utilization is not high too. Even the RAM is okay but it’s really sluggish.

Here is my setup:

DESKTOP
Intel i7 8700K
nVIDIA GTX 1080ti

[image]

Comment: Do you have a question, or is this a bug report?

Comment: About viewport animation: it seems like any more or less complicated scene tends to drop FPS drastically. Just deal with it and use OpenGL render with frame number stamp.

Comment: my bad, YES, this is actually a question!!!

Comment: Computing power is a limited resource... Most folks who ask similar questions seem to keep forgetting to mention information on what kind of scene they are dealing with, the number of triangles/faces, number of subdivisions, modifiers, physics, simulations, armatures, complexity of shaders, size of textures, etc, etc... maybe you can help others figure out what is going on in your case by adding some info on what it is you are doing. Also remember that 2.8 is still in development and there are many things that break, or are missing or are just not optimized...

Comment: That's the thing, i'm trying to find how to find the TOTAL POLY COUNT but cannot. Is this disabled by default or something i need to enable?

Comment: In 2,8 polycount is suddenly at the bottom of the window in the right part of the status bar, if that's what you'd like to know. So-called lagging can happen not only because of geometry amount but modifiers present on objects which require computations real-time. If both are present it's not admirable to face what you experience